# jQuery code to adapt a CSS class padding

Tags: jquery, css, class, padding

On my webpage [Lemendu](http://lemendu.com) I have set-up two CSS classes "redback" and "greenback", corresponding to my top-menu section "ESPAÑOL" and "FRANÇAIS" to have them on the right-hand-side.
But I have an issue with media-queries : under width 767px, the two CSS classes are not matching with the screen. I want them lined-up vertically with the other CSS classes of my top-menu (that's to say without any padding or margin).
I can't change directly my CSS class in each screen size of my media-queries file, because then, it will not match with the screens below 767px.

I have found that the only solution is to adapt directly my two CSS classes in my jQuery file to tell him that I don't want any padding. (Unless somebody have any CSS solution).
But I am totally knew in jQuery codes.

Here's my CSS two classes:

```
.redback {font-size:15px; color:#1b1c1e; padding:0px 10px 0px 120px; font-weight:400; width: 50px; position: relative; }
.greenback {font-size:15px; color:#1b1c1e; padding:0px 20px 0px 10px; font-weight:400; width: 50px; }
```

And here's my jQuery code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){


    jQuery('#nav-button').click(function() {
            jQuery('#options li').toggle();
    });

    if ( jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
    jQuery('#options li a').click(function() {
            jQuery('#options li').hide();
    });
    }

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if ( jQuery(window).width() < 767) {
    jQuery('#options li a').click(function() {
            jQuery('#options li').hide();

    jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if ( jQuery(window).width() > 767) {
            jQuery('#options li').show();
            jQuery('#options li a').click(function() {
            jQuery('#options li').show();
    });
    }
    });

});
```

I thank you in advance for your propositions, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should be using CSS media queries. You reference them, but you are not actually using any in your code.

Comment: That's why I need help, for I don't know how to build it in my jQuery file, I'm totally new to this.

Answer (score 1):

On your css media queries for:

media="all"
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
.redback and .greenback you need to remove the paddings that are pushing the text to the side. 
all you need there are the color style for each.